# Deletion of users from moodle

Tags: moodle

I have deleted users from moodle but the deleted users still show up in the users list with ability to undelete them. Is there any way to remove the deleted users from the users list.

Comment: Probably not. Hard deletion of users - or any records - is tricky in data models in general, because other entities are linked to them. Usually the best you can do is hide them from view somehow.

Comment: No idea, my test install of Moodle seems to delete users completely, so I can't even reproduce the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: Even my test install of moodle(version-3.0)also deletes the users completely but the version 2.7.3 does not shows the same behaviour.

Comment: It's a soft delete in Moodle 3.0 anyway it seems: https://imgur.com/WygBSnx . So I guess the best answer I can give you for now is "upgrade Moodle to get the UI to hide deleted users by default." I might poke at a 2.x later though.

Answer (score 1):

Only with SQL - exercise with caution though

```
DELETE FROM mdl_user WHERE deleted = 1
```

This is after you have deleted the user via the front end - which will (in theory) delete all the users data.

Comment: This sounds like a great way to do terrible things to your data.

Comment: Why? The user is deleted via the front end which generates an event telling all the plugins that the user is being deleted - so the plugins deletes the data. If the deleted indicator is 1 then it means the other data has been successfully deleted.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Moodle, but if they implemented a "soft delete" on users, wouldn't the reason to do so be so that related data does not, in fact, vanish? If you hard-delete a teacher after they quit, what happens to the grades they entered?

Comment: I mean, even if the data is consistent after the hard deletion, will it make sense anymore?

Comment: The problem that i am facing is that the deleted users are not in the database, already checked the database.The issue is though after deletion deleted users are displayed in the list.